# $.when() equivalent to fetch data

Tags: jquery

In preparation to have multiple AJAX calls that are not nested I'm trying to convert some code to use $.when().

Here is the original code that successfully fetches data from the database:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();
});

function executeAjax(parameters) {
    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'js/functions.php',
        data: parameters,
        async: true,
        cache: false
    });
}

function initialize() {
    var parameters = 
    {
     caller: caller,
     action: 'read'
    };

    executeAjax(parameters)
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('AJAX call failed');
    });
}
```

The above code causes data that was fetched from the database to be displayed in the console.

Using the recommendation from the section titled "Modularizing AJAX requests" in this link https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f here is a rewritten version of the initialize() method - my attempt to write an equivalent version using $.when():

```js
function initialize() {
    var parameters =
    {
        caller: caller,
        action: 'read'
    };

    var getList = executeAjax(parameters);

    $.when(getList).then(function(list){
        console.log(list.data);
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, the console displays "undefined" instead of the data from the database.  It references the `console.log(list.data);` as the line that's undefined.  Why isn't the rewritten version pulling back the database data?

Comment: Please add parameter as dataType: json in your $.ajax request. Because in above $.ajax request, the response comes in format as HTML. You can also do console.log(list); which will give you an better idea.

Comment: Did you tried above suggestion?

Comment: @PrasadWargad I just tried the suggestion above.  It works in the original method of initialize() but in the rewritten version of initialize() the console is still displaying `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The problem in the rewritten version was `console.log(list.data);` when that line was changed to `console.log(list);` it pulled back data from the database.